# How to cut html5 video before uploading it to server

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

i am trying to cut a video file before uploading it to my server, lie for example, if i should select a video file that's like 30 minutes, i can cut the video to upload only from 5 seconds to 60 seconds with javascript, or angularjs or ionic

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [video editor package from ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/video-editor/)

Comment: The video trim option in the plugin only works in iOS device only, I am building for android and web

Comment: @Jsdoee accordingly to the documentation, it supports android https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/video-editor/#platforms

Comment: I have used the it, the video trim option only works on iOS

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this fork have the feature you need https://github.com/dride/cordova-plugin-video-editor but it's a little outdated